# Picture In Table Cell Does Not Align Adjacent Cell

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-email, inline

I converted a PDF flyer into `HTML` after exporting from Photoshop with the use of the slice tool. When importing it into Dreamweaver, I just tweaked a few details. Structure wasn't altered. However, I'm getting a problem with an image. I can't figure out what's preventing a picture in a cell to align with adjacent cell.

http://jsfiddle.net/hbM9P/

The cell with the problem is the following:

```
<td>
 <img src="http://www.utb.edu/em/PublishingImages/2014/previewDay_emailFlyer02_06.jpg" width="302" alt="" style="display:block;">
</td>
```

By the way, the reason I'm using inline `CSS` is because I'm sending this as an `HTML` email message and [there are issues when dealing with this](http://www.outlook-apps.com/html-ignored-by-outlook/).

Answer (score 3):

Add `vertical-align:top` to that row:

```
<tr style="vertical-align:top">
    ...
    <td>
        <img src="http://www.utb.edu/em/PublishingImages/2014/previewDay_emailFlyer02_06.jpg" width="302" alt="" style="display:block;">
    </td>
</tr>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/hbM9P/4/)**

Comment: You added it to the table cell, not the entire row.

Comment: Mostly... but you missed something else there too... notice in that fiddle how the bottom is nearly aligned, but not entirely...

Comment: @Phlume - check the updated answer and fiddle. Putting the vertical-align on the row vs the cell fixes it all.

Comment: @Phlume Thank you both! That did it. Now, I'm having problem when importing the code into Outlook (desktop client). It's still messing with the code. http://i.stack.imgur.com/unyZN.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Actually... there were two problems.

The aforementioned `vertical-align:top` [Thank you j08691]

But also, that image element was missing the  `style="display:block;`

http://jsfiddle.net/hbM9P/3/

This code:

```
<td rowspan="2">
        <img src="http://www.utb.edu/em/PublishingImages/2014/previewDay_emailFlyer02_05.jpg" width="24" height="573" alt=""></td>
```

Should be:

```
<td rowspan="2">
        <img src="http://www.utb.edu/em/PublishingImages/2014/previewDay_emailFlyer02_05.jpg" width="24" height="573" alt="" style="display:block;></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

For better cross-client html email support you should actually be using html's `valign="top"` in the `<td>`, not CSS `vertical-align` as suggested in the other answers.

[vertical-align is unsupported](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) in Outlook '07,'10 and '13

Comment: It still doesn't render properly when importing the code into Outlook 2013
---
`<tr valign="top">
  <td rowspan="2">
   <img src="http://www.utb.edu/em/PublishingImages/2014/previewDay_emailFlyer02_02.jpg" width="64" height="573" alt="" style="display:block;"></td>
...</tr>`

See http://i.stack.imgur.com/unyZN.jpg

Comment: Good Point @John. Makes one wonder...has MS ever created anything that didn't need some sort of hit fix or edit to make it render on it's own without help hahah.

Comment: I ended up combining `emailFlyer02_06.jpg` and the text beneath it into a single picture. This simple conversion was turning into a frustrating task. Gmail did render it correctly both on mobile and desktop but on my computer for some reason it still had issues in contrast with a coworker's computer. We both used the same browsers when testing.

Comment: @Phlume No. It depends on your background. It is harder when you come from a web background as you have preconceptions on what should work. If you treat html email like a new programming language, it is less frustrating.

Comment: @JoeMorales You need to put the `valign="top"` in the `<td>` tag, not the `<tr>` one. In html email you never need to put anything in `<tr>` tags.